# How to access function of a contract instantiated with new?

Tags: solidity

I'm instantiating the contract called "`Elector`", applying new inside the function below, so far it works and the result is this one:

[image]

The contract is instantiated in memory with this address.

So, how do I access the `getInformation()` function inside this contract to use both in this main contract and in ethers in the **dApp**?

**MAIN CONTRACT:**

```
function updateConfirmedVotes(uint candidateId, VoteType electorVoteType) public {
        _updateTotalElectoresVoted();

        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.total += 1;
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.totalPercentage = _calculePercentageOfVote(_pollingByCandidate[candidateId].votes.total);
        _pollingByCandidate[candidateId].electors.push(new _Elector({wallet: msg.sender, vote: electorVoteType}));
    }
```

**ELECTOR CONTRACT:**

```
contract _Elector {
    address private _wallet;
    VoteType private _vote = VoteType.DID_NOT_VOTED;

    constructor(address wallet, VoteType vote) {
        _wallet = wallet;
        _vote = vote;
    }

    function getInformation() external view returns (address, VoteType) {
        return (_wallet, _vote);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a contract type variable within your `Main` contract, passing it pointer to the newly deployed `Elector` contract. Then you can invoke `external`/`public` functions defined by the contract type on the external address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Elector {
    // ...
}

contract Main {
    Elector elector;

    function deployElector() external {
        // returns pointer to the newly deployed contract
        elector = new Elector();
    }

    function getInformationFromElector() external view returns (address, Elector.VoteType) {
        // calls the external contract
        return elector.getInformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it is an array of voter contracts, should I instantiate it only once?

Comment: If you have an array of external contracts, you can store them in an array.: `Elector[] electors;` / `electors.push(new Elector());` / `return electors[index].getInformation();` ... If it's better for you to use one or multiple external contracts, depends on your use case.

Comment: Yes I do this here "`_pollingByCandidate[candidateId].electors.push(new _Elector({wallet: msg.sender, vote: electorVoteType}));`"

However, within the contract that is doing this, to use this elector's function, I need to do `address(_pollingByCandidate[0].electors[0]).getInformation()`, for example, this works.

So if I want to use the method of this contract, outside, for example in the deploy file or in the unit tests, I can't, because there is no "`address`" in `etheres`, what do I do?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS When you're deploying the `Elector` contract, you can emit an event log (from Solidity) containing the newly deployed contract address, so that offchain apps such as your ethers all is able to catch it, and then query the other contract directly... `event Deployed(address);` / `emit Deployed(address(elector));`

Comment: Interesting, with this I could get the contract that is in the memory already "decrypted" so to speak, and access the methods.

Comment: One last question, if you notice, in Struct, I added the contracts as if it were "typing" for example `_Candidate candidate` and `_Elector[] electors`.

1) Is this wrong? Yeah, for me it's compiling and deploying, so it's correct.

2) In `_Elector[]` I have a matrix without size, because I don't know the number of elements, is this also wrong and can it cause me any problems?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS If you use the separately typed contracts (from your struct) onchain (e.g. as in my original answer), than it's necessary you type them... If you use them only from offchain tools (e.g. ethers mentioned in our comments), you can safely remove the types, as ethers only recognizes them as `address` - not as typed contracts.

Comment: If I remove a type that is private from a function, for example, and put it public, the offchain (etheres) will be able to access it, right? However, how is the security issue in a dApp? Couldn't an attacker manipulate these functions that should be private?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS It depends on other context, but generally there's no way to udpate the bytecode (including data types) after it's deployed - only variable values. All address-like (e.g. `contract` or `interface`) variable types are translated to `address` once you read them offchain.